# Looking for an open source CMS with good document management- preferred Django

Tags: django, content-management-system, django-cms, dms

I'm looking for some open source Content Management System which has good support for document management. I would like to have it in a such way that anonymous user would be able to add documents(pdf,doc, etc) to some topics in a easy way.

I have some experience in Django and I could make some tweaks by myself to it, but I could take a look on the other frameworks as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Django CMS](https://www.django-cms.org/), but you have to make the templates by your own. It's not like [WP](http://wordpress.org/) or [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/) to come with ready-made themes and templates ;)

There is [Mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/) also which it comes with ready-made templates and couple of themes and also Cartridge to provide shopping cart. The thing about mezzanine is that it's not a pluggable app to use it with your own project, Mezzanine is a complete project by itself and somehow you have to start you project from it and it's not kind of thing that django people likes.

Finally [FeinCMS](http://www.feincms.org/) that I have no experience with it ;)

My suggest is go with Django CMS which is great cms app, did you get it? **app**.
means just use it as like other django apps that you are using.

Also I've released couple of plugins for it.

django-cms is very handy and customizable. Also there is another project called [django-shop](https://www.django-shop.org/) that is prefect answer for your shopping cart needs, from the mostly same devs of django-cms and it means it's totally works with django-cms.

The good things about django-cms is, it trying to follows django concepts. It's fully modular and works perfectly with other django apps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try Django CMS as it sounds interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [Mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/) or [Django CMS](https://www.django-cms.org/).

Or see Django Packages for comparison: http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/cms/